# we have 3 array and how pick 1 item from each array and push a new array using javascript

Tags: javascript

For example

const array1 = [Male, Female];

const array2 = [18-20];

const array3 = [Self Employed, Part Time, Full Time];

output will be

First Array:- [Male, 18-20, Self Employed];

Second Array:- [Male, 18-20, Part Time];

Third Array:- [Male, 18-20, Full Time];

Fourth Array:- [Female, 18-20, Self Employed];

Fifth Array:- [Female, 18-20, Part Time];

Sixeth Array:- [Female, 18-20, Full Time];

Answer (score 0):

We can do this by getting random item from each array and adding them to a new  array. we are using the pick function get a random item each item.

then we are using the for loop to create the final arrays.

```js
const pick = function(items) {
  return items[Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length)];
};

const array1 = ["Male", "Female"];
const array2 = [18,19,20];
const array3 = ["Self Employed", "Part Time", "Full Time"];

for (let index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
  var created_array = [];
  created_array.push(pick(array1));
  created_array.push(pick(array2));
  created_array.push(pick(array3));
  
  console.log(created_array);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can use foreach loop and array by array store the answer in output array

```js
const array1 = ["Male", "Female"];
const array2 = ["18-20"];
const array3 = ["Self Employed", "Part Time", "Full Time"];
let output=[];
array1.forEach((item1) => {
    array3.forEach((item2) => {
        array2.forEach((item3) => {
            output.push([item1,item3,item2]);
        })
    })
});
console.log(output);
```